# Mysql Query error in where clause on left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, rdbms

Sorry for the basic question:

```
select `plans`.`name`, `A`.`subscription_id`, `A`.`amount`, 
       `A`.`created_date`, `A`.`end_date`, 
       `A`.`subscription_status`, `users`.`email`, `A`.`plan_id`, 
       `A`.`user_id`, `usage`.`created_at` as `usagedate`,
        COUNT(usage.id) as used_count
from `subscriptions` A
left join `users` on `users`.`id` = `A`.`user_id` 
left join `plans` on `A`.`plan_id` = `plans`.`Id` 
left join `usage` on `A`.`user_id` = `usage`.`user_id` 
where `usage`.`created_at` between A.created_at and A.end_date
group by `A`.`plan_id`
```

I am getting the error

> 1054 - Unknown column 'A.created_at' in 'where clause'

Comment: sure there is a column created_at in subscriptions table?

Comment: In the `select`, you have `A.created_date`.

Comment: Sorry for the silly mistake and question. Down votes :(

Comment: More important, your query have some other issues. 1) Move the WHERE condition to the ON clause to get a real LEFT JOIN. Now it executes as a regular inner join. 2) You have missed to specify several columns in the GROUP BY. (MySQL isn't picky, I know...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there should be `A.created_date` instead of `A.created_at`

```
select `plans`.`name`, `A`.`subscription_id`, `A`.`amount`, 

`A`.`created_date`, `A`.`end_date`, 

`A`.`subscription_status`, `users`.`email`, `A`.`plan_id`, 

`A`.`user_id`, `usage`.`created_at` as `usagedate`, COUNT(usage.id) as 

used_count from `subscriptions`     A

left join `users` on `users`.`id` = `A`.`user_id` 

left join `plans` on `A`.`plan_id` = `plans`.`Id` 

left join `usage` on `A`.`user_id` = `usage`.`user_id` 

where 

`usage`.`created_at` between A.created_date and A.end_date

group by 

`A`.`plan_id`
```

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine it is meant to be `a.created_date`

```
SELECT `p`.`name`, `A`.`subscription_id`, `A`.`amount`, `A`.`created_date`, `A`.`end_date`, `A`.`subscription_status`, `u`.`email`, `A`.`plan_id`, `A`.`user_id`, `us`.`created_at` AS `usagedate`, COUNT(`us`.`id`) AS `used_count` 
FROM `subscriptions` A
LEFT JOIN `users` u on `u`.`id` = `A`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `plans` p on `A`.`plan_id` = `p`.`Id` 
LEFT JOIN `usage` us on `A`.`user_id` = `us`.`user_id` 
WHERE `us`.`created_at` between `A`.`created_date` and `A`.`end_date`
GROUP BY `A`.`plan_id`
```